# Изменить значение в списке с помощью словаря

Tags: python, list, dict

Список формата:

```
dates = ['3/января/2022', '10/февраля/2022', '17/марта/2022']
```

и словарь с месяцами:

```
months = {'января': '01', 'февраля': '02', 'марта': '03'}
```

Чтобы итоговый результат был

```
['3/01/2022', '10/02/2022', '17/03/2022']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое простое - наверное, так:

```
dates = ['3/января/2022', '10/февраля/2022', '17/марта/2022']

months = {'января': '01', 'февраля': '02', 'марта': '03'}

changed_dates = [date.replace(key, value) 
                 for date in dates 
                 for key, value in months.items() 
                 if key in date]

print(changed_dates)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ['3/01/2022', '10/02/2022', '17/03/2022']
> ```

Answer (score 3):

можно регулярку задействовать:

```
from re import sub

dates = ['3/января/2022', '10/февраля/2022', '17/марта/2022']
months = {'января': '01', 'февраля': '02', 'марта': '03'}

f = lambda m: months[m[0]]
[sub(r'[а-я]+', f, i) for i in dates]

>>>
['3/01/2022', '10/02/2022', '17/03/2022']
```

Answer (score -2):

К строке можно применить метод `.translate()`,где в качестве параметра будет передан словарь с тем что заменить(ключ) на что(значение)

```
date = '01.января.2023'
date = date.translate({'января':'01'})
```

Comment: Вы результат то смотрели? Я тоже хотел `translate` припахать, он только отдельные символы что ли переводит ))